# Why does deleting a big file take longer?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

My understanding is that running `rm` on a file simply unlinks it, marking the space as free in the filesystem. It should then follow that deleting one file always takes roughly the same amount of time (i.e. delete speed is proportional to number of files, not size of files).

So why does deleting a 15 GB file take over a minute with a simple `rm file.tar.gz`?

Comment: What filesystem?

Comment: On many file systems, each "block" of free space has to be "marked" free. Large files have more blocks. This is not true of all file systems though!

Comment: @ShaneMadden good question; ext4 right now, but I've noticed it on other ext#'s as well.

Comment: That's why every file should have it's own virtualized filesystem so the inodes can be blindly wiped super fast! <JEST>

Comment: Which filesystem would perform better at this case? I am right now using a portable drive to move large VM disks from one machine to another and rm taking forever is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It takes a constant amount of time to unlink a *single block*, but files beyond the size of a single block consist of multiple blocks linked together, and the larger the file the larger the quantity of blocks that are linked.

Comment: <BSD Zealot> *mumble mumble* UFS *mumble mumble* [soft updates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_updates) *mumble mumble* delete stuff faster *mumble mumble* pancakes! </BSD Zealot>

Comment: XFS deletes large files very rapidly, but large numbers of small files very slowly.

Comment: One file will always just use one *inode*. It does use multiple data blocks.

Comment: One block to rule them all, one block to find them, One block to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.

Comment: For anyone else wondering what this block size is: "Block size is specified at mkfs time and typically is 4KiB." More info at: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Blocks